# Installing PyMongo and bottle in cloud9 IDE

Tags: python, mongodb, bottle, cloud9-ide

How to install PyMongo and bottle in cloud9 IDE?

Comment: Have you even Google'd it? https://docs.c9.io/docs/setup-a-database

Comment: The link you've entered is irrelevant with respect to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method to install PyMongo and Bottle in Cloud9 is via **Python-pip**. Get pip first. Open your C9 terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

After pip is installed you can get PyMongo and Bottle by running the following commands:

```
sudo pip install pymongo

sudo pip install bottle
```

A tip, while specifying the localhost url enter 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost on your C9 machine. For example in your server file use,

```
bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```